# side-by-side equations, with equation numbers for each

Tags: equations, positioning, amsmath, align

The `align` command from `amsmath` allows me to put two equations side-by-side:

```
\begin{align}
x = y && a = b
\end{align}
```

Unfortunately for my purposes, this shows both equations under one equation number:

```
x = y    a = b   (1)
```

Is there any way to give them individual numbers, so that the output looks  like this?:

```
x = y (1)    a = b (2)
```

Comment: I'm trying the same thing except that I'm not intersted in having equation numbers. However, there is no space between the two equations. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
\usepackage{multicol}
...
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{equation}
    a=b
  \end{equation}\break
  \begin{equation}
    b=c
  \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: The `multicols` method is great, but it has the little drawback that  [column widths cannot be adjusted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/different-column-widths-using-multicol). :-\ This problem is overcome with Gonzalo's `minipage` method.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus 
 
The minipage method by Gonzalo is good but it doesn't maintain the vertical alignment of different equations.

Comment: @Abhinav I added `\noindent`before the first equation and removed the `\break` between them. This made the equations become vertically aligned.

Comment: Can this solution applied for the whole page?

Comment: Additionally, in order to break the column properly, you should use `\columnbreak` instead of `\break`.

Answer (score 62):

You can use `minipage`s to wrap the equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  a = b + c.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  d = e + f.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is another attempt.
The `\doubleequation` command has an optional argument to set labels. If used, it *must* be of the shape `firstlabel,secondlabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@dblLabelI {}
\newcommand*\@dblLabelII {}
\newcommand*\@dblequationAux {}

\def\@dblequationAux #1,#2,%
    {\def\@dblLabelI{\label{#1}}\def\@dblLabelII{\label{#2}}}

\newcommand*{\doubleequation}[3][]{%
    \par\vskip\abovedisplayskip\noindent
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
       \let\@dblLabelI\@empty
       \let\@dblLabelII\@empty
    \else % we assume here that the optional argument
          % has the required shape A,B
       \@dblequationAux #1,%
    \fi
    \makebox[0.5\linewidth-1.5em]{%
     \hspace{\stretch2}%
     \makebox[0pt]{$\displaystyle #2$}%
     \hspace{\stretch1}%
    }%
    \makebox[0.5\linewidth-1.5em]{%
     \hspace{\stretch1}%
     \makebox[0pt]{$\displaystyle #3$}%
     \hspace{\stretch2}%
    }%
    \makebox[3em][r]{(%
  \refstepcounter{equation}\theequation\@dblLabelI, 
  \refstepcounter{equation}\theequation\@dblLabelII)}%
  \par\vskip\belowdisplayskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  u=v
\end{equation}
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur- abitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu,
accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. 
\doubleequation[eq:2,eq:3]{a=b}{c=d}
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur- abitur
auctor semper nulla. 
\doubleequation[eq:I,eq:J]{A=B}{C=D}
Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu,
accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum. 
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:4}
  w=z
\end{equation}
We may refer to \eqref{eq:2} or \eqref{eq:3} or \eqref{eq:I} or \eqref{eq:J},
and this is compatible with \verb|hyperref|.
\end{document}
```

[image: double equation]

Comment: the spacing is deliberately set on `1/3`rd and `2/3`rd anchor points, with `3em` (randomly chosen) reserved space for the tag. It looks a bit odd compared to the centered equations though, perhaps. And there must be a better choice for the tag width.

Comment: Actually this is not an answer to this but to [another similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120670/equations-side-by-side-both-numbers-on-the-right) which already has *better* answers than my proposal. So I will remain hidden here...

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\begin{equation}
  a = b + c.
\end{equation}
&
\begin{equation}
  d = e + f.
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```