# Equations lining up and labeling

Tags: equations

I'm trying to line up multiple equations next to each other and have
them all properly labeled. There is [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32701/side-by-side-equations-with-equation-numbers-for-each) discussing
this exact problem. Unfortunately, all the solutions proposed there
produce output with the equations sitting on different baselines,
which is extremely jarring.

Here's the document I'm working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
  \qquad
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} =
    \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert
    \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert \cos \theta
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When written this way, it appears that both left-hand sides use the
same baseline and the output looks quite pleasing. Unfortunately I
couldn't achieve the same effect using the suggestions from the linked
question (which are `tabularx`, `multicol` or `minipage`).

Please help!

**Update.**
I realize that the question is a bit poorly worded. What I really want here, is an ability to arrange equations on a grid, in a way similar to how various `align` environments work, but at the same time also labeling equations that end up on the same row. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you show the code where you tried and failed to get them side-by-side?  If I wrap each of the equations in a minipage *without* a blank line between the two minipages they line up correctly, as in the linked question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `minipage` solution from the question you linked to can actually be used here, provided that you supply the second `minipage` with an optional `[b]` argument (the argument can be `t` for top, `c` for center, `b`, see [parboxes on tug](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/$5cparbox.html) and [minipages on tug](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/minipage.html) for more details).

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
 \begin{equation}
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} =
    \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert
    \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert \cos \theta
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

Following the updated question and the comments, here is an example of how you can use the above idea in a `tabular*` environment

[image: screenshot2]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\newenvironment{minipeqn}[1][]{\begin{minipage}[#1]{.45\textwidth}\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ll}
 \begin{minipeqn}
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
\end{minipeqn}&
\begin{minipeqn}[b]
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} =
    \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert
    \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert \cos \theta
\end{minipeqn}\\
\begin{minipeqn}
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
\end{minipeqn}&
 \begin{minipeqn}[b]
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} =
    \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert
    \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert \cos \theta
\end{minipeqn}\\
\begin{minipeqn}
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
\end{minipeqn}&
 \begin{minipeqn}[b]
  \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} =
    \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert
    \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert \cos \theta
\end{minipeqn}
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` to prevent a spurious blank space.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, great suggestion! Done :)

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Is it possible to extend this approach to more equations? For example, if I copy each equation environment, ending up with two equations on each page, then only the bottom equations are aligned.

Comment: @Anonymous Could you clarify: are you putting more than one `equation` environment in each `minipage`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying now to put multiple equation blocks in every `minipage` and the vertical alignment gets pretty strange. I updated the question too. Or should I just create two minipages for each row instead?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, the optional parameter in the `minipage` environment is a positional indicator. So, you can set it to `t` (top), `b` (bottom), or `c` (center).

Comment: @Anonymous Rather than putting multiple `equations` in each `minipage`, have you tried using a `tabular` environment? You could use the above idea in each row.

Comment: @cmhughes Could you give an example of using `tabular` with these equations? Simply putting them inside a `tabular` block exhibits exactly the same problem with the baseline.

Comment: @Anonymous see my edit

Comment: As an aside, there isn't a way to just put multiple `\tag`s into one equation, is there? It would make everything much simpler here.

Comment: @Anonymous not sure about multiple `\tag`s but I have updated my answer to make the code more readable using a custom environment