# Numbering a set of horizontally distributed equations

Tags: numbering, amsmath, align

Having different horizontally  distributed equations inside an `align` environment, only lines are numbered, but not individual equations.

How can the left equations be numbered using `subequations`? See also the question [side-by-side equations, with equation numbers for each](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32701/side-by-side-equations-with-equation-numbers-for-each)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align} 
      %\label{a}
        a &= a ,&
      \label{b}
        b &= b ,\\
      %\label{c}
        c &= c ,&
      \label{d}
      d &= d .
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution should be able to either:

- attach a label to the left equations, or
- modify the labels on the right to read (1a,b) and (1c,d)

I couldn't find anything in the documentation of `amsmath` or other packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a custom `nbytwosubequations` environment to number subequations two by two, line by line.

Caution: this solution assumes that each line contains two subequations; the numbering will be wrong if one line contains only one subequation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nbytwosubequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{%
    \theparentequation\alph{equation}%
    \addtocounter{equation}{1},\alph{equation}%
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{nbytwosubequations}
    \begin{align} 
      a &= a,  &
      b &= b   \label{ab} \\
      c &= c,  &
      d &= d. \label{cd}
    \end{align}
  \end{nbytwosubequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{subequations}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{align} 
      \label{a}
        a &= a, \\
      \label{c}
        c &= c ,
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{align} 
      \label{b}
        b &= b ,\\
      \label{d}
      d &= d .
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another option, adapted from an example from `mathmode`; numbering now follows the desired sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{mySubCounter}
\newcommand{\foureqn}[8]{%
\setcounter{mySubCounter}{0}
\let\OldTheEquation\theequation%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\OldTheEquation\alph{mySubCounter}}%
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
\refstepcounter{mySubCounter}
#1 &= #2 \label{sub\theequation}\\
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\addtocounter{mySubCounter}{2}
 #5 &= #6 \label{sub\theequation}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
\addtocounter{mySubCounter}{-1}%
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\begin{align}
#3 &= #4 \label{sub\theequation} \\
\addtocounter{equation}{-1} 
\addtocounter{mySubCounter}{2}
#7 &= #8 \label{sub\theequation}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip%
\let\theequation\OldTheEquation}

\begin{document}

Some references: \eqref{sub1a}, \eqref{sub1b}, \eqref{sub1c}, and~\eqref{sub1d}

\foureqn{a}{a+b,}{b+c}{b,}{d+c+e}{c,}{d}{d.}

Some other references: \eqref{sub2a}, \eqref{sub2b}, \eqref{sub2c}, and~\eqref{sub2d}

\foureqn{p+q}{r,}{s+t+u}{v+w,}{x}{y+z,}{z}{z.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Each subequation has an automatic assigned label for cross-referencing; the label is of the form `sub<number>`, where `<number>` is the string used to number the subequation.

Comment: The numbering doesn't match. I think the OP wants the first two on the first line and the last two on the second line, which is a bit trickier.

Comment: Ok, haven't thought about `minipage` command. Nice solution. Still - as @Jubobs says - the numbering goes vertically first in your example instead of horizontally. I fear I can't simply modify your solution by using horizontal aligns, as then the vertical alignment is not maintained any more. Any ideas how to fix that??

Comment: @jjdb I added another option to my answer.

Comment: @jjdb new update. Alignment and numbering are now OK.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the update. I see the labels are inside the command definition. Can your solution be used various times inside an document, or is it needed to introduce a new command for each subequations?

Comment: @jjdb with the new update you can use `\foureqn` as many times as you wish without introducing new commands. Now the labels will automatically change every time the command is invoked. Label for subequation `(3a)`, for example, will be `sub3a`, so you can simply say `\ref{sub3a}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks for the update. The example works nicely, and the result looks good. Still what worries me is the different syntax than using the usual align environment.

Comment: @jjdb and what exactly worries you? Internally, the syntax used is precisely the one of an `align` environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Now it is a command, before it was an environment.

Answer (score 4):

Not straightforward input, but it seems to work; in the image I added a vertical rule to show the middle of the page. Not perfect, either, but in my opinion this is not so good an idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftlabel}[1]{&&
  \refstepcounter{equation}\ltx@label{#1}%
  \tagform@{\theequation}&&}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{subequations}
\begin{flalign}
&&a &= a,\leftlabel{a} & b &= b \label{b} &&\\
&&c &= c,\leftlabel{c} & d &= d \label{d} &&
\end{flalign}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: what does " this" refer to in "this is not so good an idea"? Your solution or the OP's desired output?

Comment: @Jubobs The OP's desired output: associating an equation to its number is not at all immediate.

Comment: Yes, it's more difficult to parse than four subequations, each on its own line.

Comment: I agree on that. I actually favor the second requested solution, which has also been answered by @Jubobs

Comment: @jjdb Actually, I don't like the output of my solution; numbers are too close to the right-hand-side subequations, which can be confusing. I think you'd be better off dedicating one line to each subequation...

Comment: @Jubobs It looks to me as it is the same spacing as in the plain `align` environment as in the example I've provided. Already there it might be confusing (Are both equations or only te right ones numbered?). When one has more material in each equation, the asymmetric spacing should not matter that much anymore, I guess.

Comment: @jjdb Yes, it may not be problematic all the time; it's a case-by-case thing. My tip would just be: avoid any opportunity to confuse your readers :)