# Changing the order of equation numbering in minipage

Tags: numbering, minipage, multicolumn

I am trying to typeset Maxwell's equations using a `minipage`, and can't think of a good way to structure the document so the numbering of equations proceeds across the rows.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
        E = -\nabla V + \frac{\partial \bm{A}}{\partial t}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \nabla^2V+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla\cdot \bm{A}\right) = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
        \mathbf{B}=\nabla\times \mathbf{A}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \left(\nabla^2\bm{A}-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\bm{A}^2}{\partial^2t}\right)-\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot \bm{A} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)=-\mu_0 \bm{J}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I tried `multicol`, but didn't find a `multicolumn` solution as intuitive and flexible as the `minipage`. Because I'm creating two columns, I'm forced to type the second equation on the left side before the first on the right, and can't see any way around that. Can I manually change the order, or can I structure the columns differently? Thanks.

Edit: These aren't actually Maxwell's Equations. I had two sets of equations like this, and copied the second one by accident.

Comment: The obvious solution here is to set each in their own `minipage`, then you can order the first row to be numbered (1), (2) followed by (3), (4), rather than (1), (3), (2), (4).

Comment: Thanks. As you can probably tell, I'm fairly new to TeX, so these are probably obvious questions. I tried this, but now, likely because they're all separate entities, the spacing seems to be assymmetrical. The equations on the right side are thinner and are spaced closer together. http://imgur.com/OnQizYN

Comment: this might be helpful: [Numbering a set of horizontally distributed equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112796)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small amount of manual work. The two columns cannot be equal size, because of the general asymmetry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\numbereq}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{$\displaystyle}c<{$}
  @{\qquad}
  >{\numbereq}c
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{$\displaystyle}c<{$}
  @{\extracolsep{0pt}\qquad}
  >{\numbereq}c
  @{}
}
E = -\nabla V + \frac{\partial \vect{A}}{\partial t}
&\label{maxwell-one}&
\vect{B}=\nabla\times \vect{A}
&\label{maxwell-two}
\\
\nabla^2V+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\cdot \vect{A}) = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
&\label{maxwell-three}&
\left(\nabla^2\vect{A}-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\vect{A}^2}{\partial^2t}\right)
-\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot \vect{A} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)=
-\mu_0 \vect{J}
&\label{maxwell-four}
\end{tabular*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the order in which the equations appear by using separate `minipage`s for each.

Vertical alignment of equations can be achieved using a `\vphantom{<stuff>}`. This sets a zero-width box with the height of `<stuff>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
    E = -\nabla V + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{A}}{\partial t}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
    \mathbf{B}=\nabla\times \mathbf{A}
    \vphantom{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{A}}{\partial t}}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
    \nabla^2V+\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \bigl( \nabla\cdot \boldsymbol{A} \bigr) = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
  \begin{equation}
    \biggl( \nabla^2\boldsymbol{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{A}^2}{\partial^2t} \biggr)
      -\nabla \biggl( \nabla\cdot \boldsymbol{A} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} \biggr) = -\mu_0 \boldsymbol{J}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I've used [`\boldmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638/5764) from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) instead of `\bm`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `tabularx`. I define three new column types:

- Y, which is a simple `X` column with cells entering and leaving the equation environment.
- E{#1} is a `>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X` column with an equation environment.
- P{#1} is a `p{#1\linewidth} column also with an equation environment.

I defined a `tabequations` environment, which requires specifiers, which can be given in two ways:

`\begin{tabequations}{E{n1}E{n2} … E{nk}`, with the condition (as for tabularx)

`n1 + n2 + … + nk= k.`

It's up to the user to define the values of the coefficients which will realise the widths proportions he/she wants.

The other way is probably simpler and more intuitive: predefine the widths of the first columns as fractions of `\linewidth`so that the last column, of type Y, will be approximately of the required fraction of \linewidth, and the environment will not overflow the right margin.

The code of both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\usepackage{esdiff} \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\equation}>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X<{\endequation}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\equation}X<{\endequation}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\equation}p{#1\linewidth}<{\endequation}}

\newenvironment{tabequations}[1]{%
\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\par\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\tabularx{\linewidth}{#1}}%
{\endtabularx\par}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\begin{tabequations}{E{0.65}E{1.35}}
  E = -∇ V + \diffp{\bm{A}}{t}%
  & ∇²V+\diffp{}{t}\left(∇ · \bm{A}\right) = -\frac{ρ}{\epsilon₀}\\[-\abovedisplayskip]%
  \mathbf{B}=∇ × \mathbf{A} %
  & \smash{\left(∇²\bm{A}-\mu₀\epsilon₀\diffp{\bm{A}}{{t²}}\right)-∇\left(∇ · \bm{A} + \mu₀\epsilon₀\diffp{V}{t}\right)=-\mu₀ \bm{J}}
\end{tabequations}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\begin{tabequations}{P{0.35}Y}
  E = -∇ V + \diffp{\bm{A}}{t}%
  & ∇²V+\diffp{}{t}\left(∇ · \bm{A}\right) = -\frac{ρ}{\epsilon₀}\\[-\abovedisplayskip]%
  \mathbf{B}=∇ × \mathbf{A} %
  & \smash{\left(∇²\bm{A}-\mu₀\epsilon₀\diffp{\bm{A}}{{t²}}\right)-∇\left(∇ · \bm{A} + \mu₀\epsilon₀\diffp{V}{t}\right)=-\mu₀ \bm{J}}
\end{tabequations}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]