# How to increase vertical spacing between minipage and text?

Tags: spacing, minipage

I was trying to include two equations side-by-side in a document, while retaining the labels following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32702) answer.

However the spacing between the `minipage` and the text is too small.
How can I increase it to match the "default" vertical spacing used between other equations and text?

Here is the code

```
 Let us now suppose that the sequence of variables follows a stochastic
 Markov evolution model defined by

 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}%
 \begin{equation}
 \nu_{t}=\frac{\beta\nu_{t-1}}{\gamma_{t}}\label{eq:v_evolution}
 \end{equation}
 %
 \end{minipage}%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}%
 \begin{equation}
 \phi_{t}=\frac{\phi_{t-1}\gamma_{t}}{\beta}\label{eq:v_precision_evolution}
 \end{equation}
 %
 \end{minipage}

 for the variance and the precision, respectively, where $\gamma_{t}$
 is a time $t$ random impulse, with distribution
```

And here is the result:

[image: minipage spacing]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: @HarishKumar I've just added the code to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd split it that way but:

```
Markov evolution model defined by

 \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}%
 \begin{equation}
 \nu_{t}=\frac{\beta\nu_{t-1}}{\gamma_{t}}\label{eq:v_evolution}
 \end{equation}
 %
 \end{minipage}%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\columnwidth}%
 \begin{equation}
 \phi_{t}=\frac{\phi_{t-1}\gamma_{t}}{\beta}\label{eq:v_precision_evolution}
 \end{equation}
 %
 \end{minipage}

 \vspace{\belowdisplayskip}
 for the var
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks. Just out of curiosity, why do you say you wouldn't split it this way?

Comment: @RuiVieira The reader expects to see equation numbers at the same place, setting it there disturbs the reading, and unless you are very short of space and absolutely need to number both parts I'd set them as a vertical 2-line display or as a single line with a single number