# Alignment when placing equations side by side in multipage environment

Tags: equations, alignment

I have a question concering the alignment of multiple equations that are placed on one line. An earlier topic described a few methods that can be used. ([side-by-side equations, with equation numbers for each](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32701/side-by-side-equations-with-equation-numbers-for-each))

In my report I have used the multipage-approach, but I can't get the equation numbers to align vertically. I have also tried the tabularx-approach, but in that case the vertical alignment of the equations themselves is completely messed up.

Below is a MWE. I find the vertical alignment with multipage to be just fine, using the set of usepackages provided at the bottom of my post.

For the equations, I would like the vertical centers to be aligned. For the equation numbers, they should be on the same vertical line throughout the document, at the end of my textwidth or linewidth.

Does anyone know how to get all the equations aligned properly?
Thanks for your help.

```
\begin{document}

\noindent This is a very nice first equation
\begin{equation}
    1+2=3
\end{equation}
This is a very nice line of text\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
        w_{ChCl} = w_{ChCl,m} \pm \Delta w_{ChCl}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
        w_{LA} = w_{LA,m} \pm \Delta w_{LA}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
    \mbox{}\\
This is a very nice line of text\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
        M_{ChCl} = \frac{1}{MM_{ChCl}}*w_{ChCl}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
        \Delta M_{ChCl} = \frac{1}{MM_{ChCl}}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}
    \mbox{}\\

\end{document}
```

The usepackages in main: (used for all kinds of things)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,10pt]{article}

%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{scrextend} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[acronym,automake,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{symbols}{List of Symbols}
\newglossary*{compounds}{List of Compounds}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{pdflscape}   
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} } 
\usepackage{nicefrac} 
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lastpage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add the documentclass and the used packages to your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for the note. They are now added to the initial post.

Comment: Minimal means, you only add those packages that are used by the MWE (to make in compilable).

Comment: Is the problem the fact that the margins are different on even- and odd-numbered pages?  That is the default alignment of `article`, which is formatted to have pages set two-sided.  That can be changed with the `oneside` option, but that has other effects (change in handling of running heads) that may or may not be wanted.