# Labelling subequations in the same line of the equation automatically

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to automatically be able to label and reference parts of equations. To explain what I mean I'll provide an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
     w&=x   &
     y&=z
     \label{eqn:full}
     \mylabel{eqn:wx}{a}
     \mylabel{eqn:yz}{b}
\end{align}
We're talking about \cref{eqn:full}, specifically \cref{eqn:wx}.
\end{document}
```

The text should read

> We're talking about (1), specifically (1a).

How do I define `\mylabel` in order to achieve this? Of course I could use multiline equations, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:full}\begin{align}
     w&=x   \label{eqn:wx}\\
     y&=z   \label{eqn:yz}
\end{align}\end{subequations}
We're talking about \cref{eqn:full}, specifically \cref{eqn:wx}.
\end{document}
```

However, what I want is to be able to have all the equations on the same line to save space when the equations are very small. Another solution would be to simply add the >a into the text, but then if I reorder the subequations things get messy. It's ok if the equations only apear with a (1) next to them in the text, its the referencing I'm interested in.

Edit: an example that shows my issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref,cleveref,multicol}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\shock}{[}{]_{-}^{+}}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\begin{multicols}{2}
     \begin{equation}
          \shock*{(u-s) h} = 0   \label{eqn:part1}\\
     \end{equation}
     \break
     \begin{equation}
          \shock*{(u-s)^2 h + \frac{h^2}{2}} = 0  \label{eqn:part2}\\
     \end{equation}
\end{multicols}\end{subequations}
We're talking about \cref{eqn:full}, specifically \cref{eqn:part1}.
\end{document}
```

Edit2: Final version of command

```
%Multiple labeled equations on same line
\newcommand{\sidebysidesubequations}[7]{
% #1    reference label
% #2    left subequation
% #3    left label
% #5    midtext
% #6    right subequation
% #7    right label
\begin{subequations}\label{#1}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.45\linewidth}@{}p{0.55\linewidth}@{}}
        \begin{equation}
            #2  \vphantom{\textrm{#4} \quad #5} \label{#3}
        \end{equation}%
        &
        \begin{equation}
             \textrm{#4} \qquad #5 \vphantom{#2}        \label{#6}
        \end{equation}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{subequations}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very minor adaption from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32703/141947). Note that Gonzalo Medina's answer using `minipage`s is better if you wish to adapt the width of each subequation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref,cleveref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:full}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{equation}
            w=x   \label{eqn:wx}
        \end{equation}\break
        \begin{equation}
            y=z   \label{eqn:yz}
        \end{equation}
    \end{multicols}
\end{subequations}

We're talking about \cref{eqn:full}, specifically \cref{eqn:wx}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Due to the vertical alingment problem, it feels like a `tabularx/vphantom` -based solution is more relevant.
Basically, both cells of the `tabularx` share the same height due to the

```
contentcell1 \vphatom{contentcell2}
```

structure.

I wrapped all the code into a `newcommand` to ease the use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,hyperref,cleveref,tabularx}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\shock}{[}{]_{-}^{+}}

\newcommand{\sidebysidesubequations}[3]{%
% 1st argument is the reference label
% 2nd argument is the left subequation
% 3rd argument is the right subequation
% Sublabels are defined with suffixes -left and -right
    \begin{subequations}\label{#1}
        \noindent
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
         \begin{equation}
              #2 \vphantom{#3}  \label{#1-left}
         \end{equation}%
         &
         \begin{equation}
              #3 \vphantom{#2} \label{#1-right}
         \end{equation}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{subequations}
}

\begin{document}
\sidebysidesubequations{eqn:full}{
    \shock*{(u-s) h} = 0
}{
    \shock*{(u-s)^2 h + \frac{h^2}{2}} = 0
}
We're talking about \cref{eqn:full}, specifically \cref{eqn:full-left}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Eddy, I have a feeling, that it may not be what you really ask for. You say you want to label parts of equations, but your maths shows two equations. The answer above is not *automatic* per se, but has the two references and both equations are on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for your respnse. The issue with the solutions cited question is that they mess up the vertical alignment that the align environment gives. Using this solution in my actual document results in the (1a) and (1b) not being vertically aligned...

Comment: @Eddy, could you update your MWE sot that it shows this issue ?

Comment: added a new example

Comment: @Eddy I updated my answer. Be careful when you write an MWE to be sure that it compiles. For instance `amsmat` does **not** provide `DeclarePairedDelimiter`, `mathtools` does.

Comment: thanks for your help, it seems it was \vphantom I needed to know!

Comment: You're welcome !