# Formating Maxwell's Equations

Tags: align, amsmath, labels, subequations, grouping

Hey y'all I am trying to format Maxwell's equations like the image below but without the box. I also want to be able to reference the labels, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried? Is there something specific you don't know how to do?

Comment: You can build on this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32703.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome! This is to give you a start. All I did was to employ [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32702), to use the `leqno` option to move the equation numbers to the left and change the numbering scheme to become roman.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}
\begin{document}
Equations \eqref{eq:Maxwell1}--\eqref{eq:Maxwell4} are\par
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{align}
    \bm{\nabla}\cdot\bm{D} &=4\pi\rho_{f}\;,\label{eq:Maxwell1}
    \vphantom{\frac{\partial\bm{B}}{\partial t}}\\
    \bm{\nabla}\cdot\bm{B} &=0\;,\vphantom{\frac{\partial\bm{B}}{\partial t}}\label{eq:Maxwell2}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{align}
    \bm{\nabla}\times\bm{E} &=-\frac{\partial\bm{B}}{\partial t}\;,\label{eq:Maxwell3}
    \\
    \bm{\nabla}\times\bm{H} &=\bm{J}_f
    +\frac{\partial\bm{D}}{\partial t}\;.\label{eq:Maxwell4}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\smallskip

Equation \eqref{eq:Maxwell1} is \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future I'd kindly ask you to show us what you have tried. That spares others from punching in these equations.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Sorry about that I'll make sure to post my attempt next time.