# LaTeX alligned numbered equations

Tags: equations, overleaf, alignment

I am trying to align two vector definitions next to each other. Both equations are (and should be) numbered. I found a [similar (answered) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32701/side-by-side-equations-with-equation-numbers-for-each?newreg=e6ec11f833d94ef7ae9cfaec8666ac23) on Stack but my equations doesn't seem to align properly. [image]

This is my code

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:va}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{v}_a =  \begin{pmatrix} 
    {\alpha_1} \\ {\alpha_2} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\alpha_{T-1}} \\ {\alpha_T} \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}\break

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:vc}
    \begin{aligned}
        \textbf{v}_c =  \begin{pmatrix} 
        {\beta_1} \\ {\beta_2} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\beta_{T-1}} \\ {\beta_T} \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. I'll add the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of two minipages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:va}
    \begin{aligned}
      \textbf{v}_a =  \begin{pmatrix} 
      {\alpha_1} \\ {\alpha_2} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\alpha_{T-1}} \\ {\alpha_T} \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned} 
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:vc}
    \begin{aligned}
        \textbf{v}_c =  \begin{pmatrix} 
        {\beta_1} \\ {\beta_2} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\beta_{T-1}} \\ {\beta_T} \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned} 
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some further web-search gave me the answer.

1 ) Remove `\break`
2 ) Add `\noindent` before the first equation

[image]
Correct code:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:va}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{v}_a =  \begin{pmatrix} 
    {\alpha_1} \\ {\alpha_2} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\alpha_{T-1}} \\ {\alpha_T} \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:vc}
    \begin{aligned}
        \textbf{v}_c =  \begin{pmatrix} 
        {\beta_1} \\ {\beta_2} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\beta_{T-1}} \\ {\beta_T} \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```